Retrieve and provide JWT Token for GraphQL in Appsmith
I need to perform the following actions: add Google login. After the user logs in through Google, obtain the accessToken and pass this token to another endpoint, which will return a JWT token for accessing the GraphQL URL. Then, using this JWT token, make calls to the GraphQL server to retrieve data and display it in Appsmith.
Could you please let me know if this is possible with the Appsmith Community Edition, and if so, what exact steps I need to follow in Appsmith to configure this?
